# is this the method for comparing an interger which i made it str to check if is a string List?

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am trying to compare an "i" counter whitch is interger with a list whitch inludes str numbers , and add it in a string variable

```
LPL = ["1","2","3"]

f = str()

for i in range (x):

    if str(i) == LPL[i]:

      f+=str(i)
```

i expected the f variable had the result of the comparsion: f = 123

Comment: The code you posted won't run due to the undefined variable `x`.  Perhaps you want `len(LPL)` instead.

Comment: i have t post the whole code, the variable x contains the len of the LPL

Comment: So just change `x` to `len(LPL)`. And your problem is probably that `range` starts counting from `0`. By your expected output you probably want to do `if str(i+1) == LPL[i]:`

Answer (score 0):

List index starts from `0`:

```
LPL = ["1","2","3"]
s = ""
for i in range(1,len(LPL)+1):
    if i == int(LPL[i-1]):
       s+=str(i)

print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you should use a `range` from a number to a number and also that `python` indexes starts from `0`, so you need to adapt the code in a way like:

```py
LPL = ["1","2","3"]

f = str()

for i in range (1, len(LPL)+1):
    ### note that your LPL[0] == 1 and not LPL[1] == 1, so you need to decreasee a number here, that's why a +1 in the range too
    if str(i) == LPL[i-1]:
      f+=str(i)

### OUTPUT
>>> f
'123'
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I missing something, but if you wish to combine the elements of the list, either by conjoining strings or adding integers, consider using reduce:

```
LPL = ["1","2","3"]
LPL2 = [1,2,3]

f = reduce(lambda a,b : a+b, LPL)     # "123"
f_int = reduce(lambda a,b : a+b, LPL)  # 6
```